# Создание и запуск несколько независимых экземпляров существующего приложения

Tags: база-данных, windows, docker, контейнеры

Задача:
Есть приложение, которое сохраняет и анализирует определенные данные в БД. Приложение немногопользовательское и работает только на Windows. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы на сервере открывалось более 5(несколько сотен :)) независимых экземпляров данного приложения, но каждое со своей БД. Для удаленного доступа должны использоваться разные порты на каждый экземпляр приложения.

Кто-то посоветовал сделать это через docker, начал его активно изучать, но пока всё равно не могу сообразить принцип, как это сделать. Мне не нужно создавать образы ОС Windows(чтобы не тратить ресурсы на виртуализацию ОС), ОС применяется текущая на сервере. Если правильно понимаю, нужно создать контейнеры для каждого экземпляра ПО и как-то связать их с БД??? Можно ли так вообще сделать?

Возможно есть другие способы решения задачи. С удовольствием о них узнал бы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135241/discussion-on-question-by-maks------).